# Server Error while using Next js and React

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Layout } from '../components'
import '../styles/globals.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  ) 
}

export default MyApp
```

The layout component, the one I think I am facing a problem with.

```
import React  from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';

import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Footer from './Footer';

const Layout = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <Head>
        <title>Ecss</title>
      </Head>
      <header>
        <Navbar />
      </header>
      <main className="main-container">
        {children}
      </main>
      <footer>
        <Footer />
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

This is also the layout component

I am facing a problem with this code I am getting a server error:

[image]

I am trying to wrap `<component {...pageProps}/>` with the `<Layout>` tag.

Comment: Can you post the Layout component code here?

Comment: components is file or folder ?

Comment: import React, { Children } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';

import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Footer from './Footer';

const Layout = ({childer}) => {
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <Head>
        <title>JS Mastery Store</title>
      </Head>
      <header>
        <Navbar />
      </header>
      <main className="main-container">
        {Children}

      </main>
      <footer>
        <Footer />
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout

Comment: The components is a folder

Comment: Please, try to properly format your question so it's easier for us to understand your problem :)

Comment: I formatted it I hope it looks better now. sorry still new to the formatting.

Comment: Just to be sure, if you remove the `Layout` component, the error is gone?

Comment: yes removing Layout it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You have exported your Layout component as a default export, when you use default export to export something you don't have to use curly brace when you import that file.

just remove the curly bracers of the Layout component in the MyApp file,

change this, `import { Layout } from '../components'` to this `import Layout from '../components'`

Comment: I did try to remove it but the problem is still there sadly.

Answer (score 0):

`import  {Layout}  from '../components'`

In the Layout file, you exported Layout as default, hence no braces should be wrapping it. Only use this when you export such as `export const ...`.

Here's your fix:

`import  Layout  from '../components'`

Comment: I did try it still shows the same error.

Comment: Make sure all other components you're importing are being imported in the correct structure. This error is almost always because of a wrong import.

Comment: By any chance is the problem that I have the files written as (filename).js rather than (filename).jsx?

Comment: That could be a problem yes, if you're including a JSX Element  in a file then that file MUST have a `.jsx` extension; otherwise it's fine.

Comment: OP might have an index file with named exports in the components folder.

Comment: Using the `.jsx` extension is not required by default in Next.js.